# Regexp: Identify a string with Name Sourname

Tags: regex

Hello I have written a regular expression for swapping a name and sourname:

```
find \"([A-Z][a-z]+)\s([A-Z][a-z]+)\" replace "\2 \1"
```

However I have now discovered that I should not swap everything I find inside brackets but only particoular candidate names such as:

- John Doe
- Jayne Eyre

For example if I find Jayne Doe it should not be swapped (so \"(Eyre|Doe)\s(John|Jayne)\" is excluded from the possible solutions).

Any advice. Thanks?

Comment: What excactly are the properties that distinguish names to be switched from those that should not be?

Comment: I should only switch Names John Doe and Jayne Eyre only. Not mixing of names and Sournames like Jayne Doe or John Eyre.

EDIT: I have a list of couples of names and sournames that should be swapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the number of names to be switched is fairly small, this might work for you:

```
(?: (?<A>John)\s(?<B>Doe) | (?<A>Jayne)\s(?<B>Eyre) | (?<B>\w+)\s(?<A>\w+) )
```

I have included white space for readability; be sure to take it out or use the regex option that ignores it. I used [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm), so the regexes are in the .Net syntax, but I think you can tweak it as needed.

The replacement regex is:

```
${B} ${A}
```

The regex has 3 alternatives; 2 (or more) for the names that we want to switch, and one for all other names that should not be switched. The name parts are defined with named capture groups (A & B) that are used by the replacement regex to do the switching. The trick is just that in the third alternative, we swap the named capture groups so that names that we do not want to switch are actually switched, but to no effect.

More complicated name variations (John C. Reilly, Olivia Newton-John) will not work, but as your original regex kept it simple, I followed suit.

Updated answer......

It seems Flex regexes do not support named groups in the replacement regex. After experimenting, I have come up with a variation of my original idea that only uses numbered capture groups and seems to work:

```
(John)\s(Doe)|(Jayne)\s(Eyre)|(\w+)\s(\w+)
```

The replacement regex is:

```
$2$4$5 $1$3$6
```

This is quite a bit more of a hack than the original, but again, if the number of names to be switched is reasonable, it might be workable. In my testing, given above regex and replacement regex and the following input:

```
John Doe
Jayne Eyre
Bob Smith
```

I got the following output:

```
Doe John
Eyre Jayne
Bob Smith
```

Comment: Ok Darril. Thanks so far I have come to this regex **([0-9]+\s*,\s*)?\"((Pink)\s(Dolly)|(Doe)\s(John)|(Eyre)\s(Jane))\"** but when I try the matches on x=("Doe John", x, v[--e], 44, "Eyre Jane"); i got those response: [link](http://pastebin.com/0T7dwx1J). Since i can only use \p syntax (p identifies the group number p) for the replace I have a problem since Jayne Eire is not on the same match number as john doe

Comment: What language/Regex flavor are you using Mattias? Maybe I can help tweak the Regexes to work with it. And could you put a sample of your input text in pastebin? I guess you kept it simple in the original question, but now I'm unclear and think it would be helpful to see what it really looks like.

Comment: I must provide them in the syntax of (f)lex or alex. I am using regulator for testing.

Comment: Mattias, I experimented using a Flex Regex testing tool (http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) but it looks like my idea won't work because Flex doesn't seem to support named groups in a replacement Regex. Sorry!

Comment: Mattias, I gave it another try, please see my updated answer.